# Is it possible to detect the user click event in the popup window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xss, jquery-events

I can detect the user click event in the popup window if the current url and popup url is in same domain using the following code:

```
var myWindow = window.open("abc.html","MsgWindow", "width=500","height=600");
$(myWindow).on('click', 'a', function() {alert('a')});
```

But, Is it possible to detect the user activity from the external url as below?

```
var myWindow = window.open("http://google.com","MsgWindow", "width=500","height=600");
$(myWindow).on('click', 'a', function() {alert('a')});
```

The second snippet is not working for me. How can I make it work?

Comment: no you can not! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: No. I'm not getting any error. Javascript is not detecting the click event in the popup :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't becouse of SOP (Same Origin Policy) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

To give you an example:
You make a popup to a webpage with a login. With your method you are able to track the key input of the login information. username and password. Thats would be a major secutiry issue.

Comment: Ya. You are right..

But, How addmefast.com detecting the user likes in the popup window ?

Comment: Could you provide direct link of this behaviour on addmefast.com or way to replicate it?

Comment: keep in mind its possible (i guess with headers) to allow a different domain access via javascript!

Comment: @ggzone: i do not think its possible unless cross domain server has mentioned access control origin to access from other domains.